# Setting element content of an XSD element that has attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm having difficulty declaring an element that contains a text string and has two text attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This schema is not valid -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Favorite" type="xs:string">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="car"    type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="fruit" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>       
</xs:schema>
```

The schema passes if I drop the attributes, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="Favorite" type="xs:string">
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Or if I omit the `type="xs:string"` in `<xs:element name="Favorite" type="xs:string">`.

The desired schema is supposed to validate the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Favorite car="Volvo" fruit="banana">These are a few of my favorite things</Favorite>
```

PS: *I'm sorry if this question is rather trivial. I'm still a beginner at XSD.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_text.asp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Favorite">
        <xs:complexType>

            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="car" type="xs:string"/>                 
                    <xs:attribute name="fruit" type="xs:string"/>   
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>

        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```